# How to SFTP with PHP?

Tags: php, sftp

I have came across many PHP scripts for web FTP clients. I need to implement a SFTP client as a web application in PHP.
Does PHP support for SFTP? I couldn't find any samples.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 81):

PHP has ssh2 stream wrappers (disabled by default), so you can use sftp connections with any function that supports stream wrappers by using `ssh2.sftp://` for protocol, e.g.

```
file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://user:pass@example.com:22/path/to/filename');
```

or - when also using the [ssh2 extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php

On a side note, there is also quite a bunch of questions about this topic already:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sftp+php

Comment: file_get_contents and file_put_contents both work awesome. never knew they worked with sftp and it's so much easier than using the built in sftp stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Even when using file_get_contents() you still need the ssh2 extension (afaik).

Comment: debian/ubuntu packages : apt install libssh2-1-dev php-ssh2

Comment: This answer doesn't seem correct. SFTP uses an encrypted private key to provide its security, so it requires the pathname of a private key and its passphrase in any PHP solution. The answer does not provide this functionality. I don't know why it got so many upvotes.

Comment: @DavidSpector that depends only on settings of server. You can have regular USER/PASS combination even with SFTP/SSH.

Comment: I think you mean that you can have a password in addition to using SFTP. True.

Answer (score 45):

The ssh2 functions aren't very good.  Hard to use and harder yet to install, using them will guarantee that your code has zero portability.  My recommendation would be to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @indranama would you mark this as the correct answer so that future users don't have to read comments to find which worked best for you?

Comment: phpseclib isn't any easier to install, just my experience

Answer (score 32):

I found that "phpseclib" should help you with this (SFTP and many more features). http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

To Put the file to the server, simply call (Code example from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#put)

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

// puts a three-byte file named filename.remote on the SFTP server
$sftp->put('filename.remote', 'xxx');
// puts an x-byte file named filename.remote on the SFTP server,
// where x is the size of filename.local
$sftp->put('filename.remote', 'filename.local', NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: The git repo is here: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/master/phpseclib

Comment: Can you update your answer to phpseclib 2.0? Your current example is obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

**Install Flysystem v1:**

```
composer require league/flysystem-sftp
```

**Then:**

```
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Sftp\SftpAdapter;

$filesystem = new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter([
    'host' => 'example.com',
    'port' => 22,
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'privateKey' => 'path/to/or/contents/of/privatekey',
    'root' => '/path/to/root',
    'timeout' => 10,
]));
$filesystem->listFiles($path); // get file lists
$filesystem->read($path_to_file); // grab file
$filesystem->put($path); // upload file
....
```

**Read:**

https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v1/docs/

**Upgrade to v2:**

https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/advanced/upgrade-to-2.0.0/

***Install***

```
 composer require league/flysystem-sftp:^2.0
```

***Then:***

```
//$filesystem->listFiles($path); // get file lists
$allFiles = $filesystem->listContents($path)
->filter(fn (StorageAttributes $attributes) => $attributes->isFile());

$filesystem->read($path_to_file); // grab file
//$filesystem->put($path); // upload file
$filesystem->write($path);
```

Comment: Answer is no longer valid since the methods changed. No put or read available anymore!

Comment: @Mr.Jo they are if you look at the v1 docs

Comment: @Wanjia At StackOverflow we drive with the time I think. So it would be good to keep the answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

After messing around with PECL ssh2 I decided to take a look at phpseclib 3 and it worked out of the box. No installation on the server. I used composer to install it and put the code in. It has a ton of useful things and it's free. These are the steps:

1. Run this composer install on your PHP app folder. I used VS Code and I opened a terminal window (need [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to be installed on your machine first):

   composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0
2. Use the basic example from here: https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp

   use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;

   $sftp = new SFTP('localhost');

   $sftp->login('username', 'password');

   $sftp->put('filename.remote', 'filename.local', SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);

Other useful links: GitHub: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib and website: https://phpseclib.com/

Answer (score -1):

I performed a full-on cop-out and wrote a class which creates a batch file and then calls `sftp` via a `system` call. Not the nicest (or fastest) way of doing it but it works for what I need and it didn't require any installation of extra libraries or extensions in PHP.

Could be the way to go if you don't want to use the `ssh2` extensions

Comment: related thread that helped me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.security.ssh/_55TdDdUTCw