# PHP Install SSH2 on Windows machine

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll, libssh2

I am trying to install [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) on a `Windows+Apache` machine.
Documentation says that SSH2 requires the `OpenSSL` and `libssh2` libraries.
I have added this lines in my `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_ssh2.dll
```

and restarted Apache but it still not working (`Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()`).

Can anyone explain me how to install this service?

Answer (score 30):

Here's how I did it:

1. Downloaded Win32 SSH2 PECL extension from [this location](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/)
   (choose the appropriate version);
2. Extracted the archive's content and:

   - placed `php_ssh2.dll` and `php_ssh2.pdb` files in the `ext` folder (e.g. `C:\php\ext`);
   - copied `libssh2.dll` file to `C:\Windows\system32` and (if you got Win64) `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder(s);
3. Run the following command to register the DLL:

   ```
   C:\> regsvr32 libssh2.dll
   ```
4. Restarted Apache.

**Final note**

If you got PHP x64, you have to lookup for the x64 version of the SSH2 library / DLLs.
[This site](http://www.anindya.com) offers some Win64 compiled libraries for PHP, try here first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to setup this for command line use with Phing. Followed your instructions, `php -i` says `SSH2 support enabled`, however attempt to run Phing task ends up with windows message about PHP crashing. Any hints how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Got resolved by updating everything and anything in web stack to latest versions. Probably some DLL conflict or whatever.

Comment: ...applied to systems with PHP 5.3.27 and PHP 5.4.15 versions. Worked flawlessly!

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.6 and I'm probably out of luck, there's no .dll to download and vc11 isn't compatible.

Comment: @Christian: I'm stuck needing this with PHP5.6 too...if you figure something out, PLEASE let us know :)

Comment: For PHP 7.1, I had to get from this location: http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/1.1.2/windows    (the thread-safe version).  I copied those files into my php/ext dir as described in this answer.  Trying to run the regsvr32 didn't work for me, but I am not sure it was even necessary.  I found a copy of libssh2.dll in the php dir already there.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone is having trouble installing SSH2, here's how I did it:

1) Download SSH2 PECL library from [PHP.net](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) [choose the appropriate version].

2) Copy `libssh2.dll` to **System32** [x86] or **SysWOW64** [x64] folder.

3) Copy `php_ssh2.dll` and `php_ssh2.pdb` to **php/ext** folder.

4) Remove ';' from the `;extension=php_ssh2.dll` line in php.ini. If this line is not on your php.ini, add it.

5) Restart **Apache**.

Comment: On xampp I had to copy  libssh2.dll to C:\xampp\php folder but when I run the script. xamp stops working.

Comment: Place the extension DLL file in the "ext" sub folder of PHP instead, where it belongs to.

Comment: libssh2.dll is not in the download files! where should I get it?

Answer (score 8):

1. Place `php_ssh2.dll` in ext folder
2. Place `libssh2.dll` in php folder
3. Restart `IIS`

that work for me

- `PHP 5.4.25 NTS + Windows Server 2012`

Comment: I personally (on Windows 7) had to add these libs to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (on 32bit that is `C:\Windows\System32` )

Answer (score 5):

If you are running xamp 3.2.1 and PHP 5.6.8, this could be helpful for you.

Do what alex b said, and download the package that corresponds dependindg your php version (and bits) from this page ([link](https://phpfashion.com/php-ssh2-dll-for-php-5-6-and-7-0))

I've downloaded and replaced in C:\xampp\php\ext and it worked!

Hope this helps, regards.

Comment: The 5.6 x86 version of the DLL contains malware. Do not know about others.

Answer (score 4):

libssh2 (deps): http://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps/

php_ssh2 (ext): http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/

Versions prior to 5.5 has already the libssh2.dll (from the second link)

Answer (score 4):

I have wamp with PHP 5.6.25/7.0.10 – MySQL 5.7.14 installed and I cm currently working on PHP 7.0. I had the same error. I checked using phpinfo() if both librarires OpenSSL and libssh2 was working(you can google how to check it). After I could see they was working, I have downloaded php_ssh2.dll at http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/1.0/windows (can also be found http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/ ) for the 7.0 version, put it to php\ext folder. Than I included it in php.ini file using extension=php_ssh2.dll.

Then it appeared at phpinfo(). And it worked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Fix that worked for me. Am running xampp v. 3.2.1 apache 2.2 facing the same issue tried placing the dll files at different c: location but failed finally this helped.

1.) Download the version specific dll files from http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/0.12/windows and extract the files

**Note that even though you are in 64 bit version of windows download the 32 version of THREAD SAFE ssh i.e. Thread Safe (TS) x86 as per your version of php**

2.) Add/replace the libssh2.dll  at C:\xampp\php (standard  installation)

3.) Add/replace the php_ssh2.dll & php_ssh2.pdb within the C:\xampp\php\ext (standard  installation)

4.) restart the apache server

*Worked Like a charm*

CHEERS

Comment: Can you please let me know from where can I get libssh2.dll and php_ssh2.dll for Version: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.6 on x86 Architecture. Checking phpinfo.php, it shows me that OpenSSL is enabled. I am finding it hard to get proper dll. Tried many but none works for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question reveals two misconceptions:

1. The [Requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.requirements.php) section actually says this:

   > The » OpenSSL and » libssh2 libraries are required. Ensure that the
   >   development libraries are installed, where a typical package name
   >   might be openssl-dev.

   It isn't talking about PHP extensions, it's talking about third-party libraries that have nothing to do with PHP.
2. `extension=php_ssh2.dll` requires that you actually have a file called `php_ssh2.dll` in your PHP's `ext` directory and you probably don't have it, mainly because it isn't bundled with PHP.

If we check the [Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) chapter we can read that SSH2 is a PECL extension. There're a few links with instructions but I can make a summary of the important info:

- You need a `php_ssh2.dll` file that matches your PHP installation.
- Neither the PHP team nor the PECL team distribute such file.
- Installing PECL extensions on Windows is hard. You need to download the C source code, grab a C compiler and make the file yourself, or find someone who already did it for you.

Said that, unless you Google for `php_ssh2.dll` and find something relevant, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I have **php_ssh2.dll** on my server, I've downloaded it here: http://www.php.net/releases/#5.2.6 >> PECL 5.2.6 Win32 binaries

Comment: Maybe you can suggest me another method to SFTP through PHP with key?

Comment: @LaYle - Are you using PHP/5.2.6?

Comment: @LaYle - There appear to be many questions already. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4689595/13508) suggests that PHP has builtin support :-?

Comment: For what it's worth, Windows releases of php_ssh2 are available at http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/.