# I want to use SSH2 with zendframework. Also need steps for installation and configuration with wamp server

Tags: zend-framework2, wamp

I want to use SSH2 with zendframework. Also need steps for installation and configuration with wamp server. PHP function ssh2_connect is not working.

It showing the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /home/chaosnz/public_html/fotosnap.net/test.php on line 2

How can I deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine

Answer (score 0):

Run:

`/usr/local/zend/bin/pecl install ssh2 channel://pecl.php.net/ssh2-0.12`

I was having the same problem. */usr/local/zend/bin/pecl install ssh2* outputs:

```
Failed to download pecl/ssh2 within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.12, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/ssh2-0.12" to install
install failed
```

When I added channel://pecl.php.net/ssh2-0.12 it compiled fine. It will then ask you:

```
You should add "extension=ssh2.so" to php.ini
```

I've added that to /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/ssh2.ini, restarted httpd and now ssh2_connect() is working. Good luck!