# How to connect to sftp server via php

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, sftp

I am using PHP , I want to connect to remote server in SFTP, but the website said:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in D:\xampp\htdocs\dive\database.php on line 9**

Can you tell me in detail how to do this? I tired

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('ftp.server.com', 22); 
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password')) 
    echo "Authentication success";
else 
    echo "Authentication failure";
?>
```

But it doesn't work.

After I connect to the server, is there a difference if I want to insert some data to the table in it? Which function should I use?

Comment: Did you install and configure ssh2? http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.setup.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed / verified via phpinfo() that ssh2 is installed?
Quick Google search seems to indicate it is not by default
[PHP Install SSH2 on Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine)