# Getting error when loading libssh2.dll

Tags: php, libssh2

I m trying to install ssh2. So I put the libssh2.dll file windows\system32 folder than using cmd I m trying to load this file as meanion [PHP Install SSH2 on Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine)

I wrote

```
regsvr32 libssh2.dll
```

After this I m getting following error.

```
The module "libssh2.dll" was loaded but the entry-pointDllRegisterServer was not found.
Make sure that "libssh2.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try it again
```

Answer (score 0):

try execute "regsvr32 /i "C:\full_path_here\libssh2.dll". I usually put my dlls inside system32 (on x86) windows or syswow64 (on x64)