# enable php_ssh2 on Windows 8

Tags: php, windows-8.1, sftp

I am trying to use php_ssh2 to send commands via sftp to a raspberry pi from a windows server with xampp as web server and PHP 5.5.
I could not make it work although I followed the procedure at [PHP Install SSH2 on Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine).
Maybe there are some updates for Windows 8.
When I try to register libssh2.dll i get an error (it is not a valid .dll) although I downloaded the latest version.
If I execute php -i I get this error: "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ssh2.dll' - it is not a valid Win-32 Application"
The operation system is Windows 8 64bit.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

It has a number of [advantages over libssh2](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/compare.html):

- more portable.
- easier to use.
- faster
- better public key support
- etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how to set it into a zf2 project?

Comment: I updated composer.json in my root folder:     "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"phpseclib\\": "vendor/phpseclib/"}
    }  ; i downloaded the package and saved into vendore/phpseclib. then I called phpseclib in a controller in Application. "use phpseclib" .... and then "$ssh = new Net_SSH2(ip)" but i get a Fatal error "Class not found"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find

```
Architecture - 32 bit or 64 bit or 86 bit
compiler version - VC9 or VC11 or VC14
Thread safe or Non thread safe
```

This can be find by open phpinfo or echo phpinfo() in any php file. Then search for Compiler,Architecture and Thread Safety

Then go to http://windows.php.net/download/ and download right Releases. Replace needed file then restart web server

Answer (score -1):

download library for **x64** system, here >

ssh2 library 0.12 [for PHP 5.5 - Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/php_ssh2-0.12-5.5-nts-vc11-x64.zip)

ssh2 library 0.12 [for PHP 5.5 - Thread Safe (TS) x64](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/php_ssh2-0.12-5.5-ts-vc11-x64.zip)