# What is the replacing code for command prompt in php for 'apt-get install libssh2-php' in linux?

Tags: drupal, civicrm

I am currently working with the MERCI module for event reservation and I need to add the user management for the MERCI and it needs another module called CIVICRM and the installation is little bit difficult and it needs do to some configurations.

I am going to install civicrm for drupal 7 for that I need to change the install settings and here is the code given in a tutorial to follow in order to change the php ssh settings?

```
apt-get install libssh2-php
```

Can anyone help me to get the code for the command prompt in windows, because the above one is for linux. 
I am referring to the article in the following link...
[Installation of civicrm in drupal 7](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Drupal+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5+-+Drupal+7)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine