# php: how to install libssh2 for sftp file uploading?

Tags: php, windows-10

I want to know the solution in step by step answers for SFTP file uploading. if I run the program I got the error like this...

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9**

I am using xampp with PHP 7.2.6 version.

Comment: Please take a look at the following answer.[Installing ssh2 on xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920250/installing-ssh2-on-xampp)

Comment: but I expect the perfect result. I tried a lot of ways but still i don't get solution

Answer (score 0):

1. Head to the [SSH2 PECL extension download page](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) and download the appropriate version of this extension for you.
2. Extract the downloaded file.
3. Copy the `.dll` file in the extracted folder to the extension folder of your PHP installation
4. Enable extension in your `php.ini` file.

Unfortunately, I'm that the current windows build of this extension has not supported PHP 7.2 yet.

Comment: Compiled version of SSH2 for PHP 7.2 on Windows can be found at https://github.com/nufue/pecl-ssh2-windows