# PHP 5.6 ssh2_connect() extension

Tags: php, apache, ssh, php-extension

I trying to install the php_ssh2.dll extension on a

- Windows 2012 Rc2 64bit System
- Apache 2.4.26
- php 5.6.31

for ssh2_connect() ... i want to open a sftp connection

1.) I toke the `libssh2.dll` into `/System32` and `/syswow64` folder

2.) the `php_ssh2.dll` and `php_ssh2.pdb` into `/xampp/php/ext` folder

3.) modified `php.ini` (add `extension=php_ssh2.dll`)

4.) restarted Apache

I start my example script an result:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

Now, I'm not sure how I can solve this issue, maybe someone has any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Install SSH2 on Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine)

Comment: yes, I tried this also `C:\> regsvr32 libssh2.dll` but I got a error message "the module "libssh2.dll" failed to load"

Comment: The appache Error Log has an entry about: "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_ssh2.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Try this: https://phpfashion.com/php-ssh2-dll-for-php-5-6-and-7-0

Answer (score 3):

I tested a lot the last few hours.
Update to php 7.1,
used some other versions of `php_ssh2.dll` / `libssh2.dll`, tried to install the dll on Windows by Powershell (regsvr32.exe) ... nothing works with `ssh2_connect($ftp_server, 22);`

!But I found a other solution by using `curl()`

here is my example (it works!)

```
 <?php

 $ftp_server = 'xxx'; $ftp_user_name = 'xxx'; $ftp_user_pass = 'xxx';

 $c = curl_init("sftp://$ftp_user_name:$ftp_user_pass@$ftp_server/folder/file.xxx");
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP); $data =
 curl_exec($c); curl_close($c);

 if ($data === false){echo 'err';}else{echo 'done';}

?>
```