# What is the best and easiest way to access files within a linux vps using its external ip?

Tags: php, linux, ftp

I have a game server running in a `vps` with `centos 6` .
The game server stores its status data on a text file and i want to access this file from my website server with `php`.
The problem is that it is better to do it without installing something link ftp server on the `vps`. Also i do not know how to set the ftp account directory to my game server directory.
Anyone knows any other simpler way to do so ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any kind of webserver installed on your vps? (like apache or node+express)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. And it is better to resolve the problem without installing a web server or at least resolving it by installing a simple software that uses less ram. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a client which supports SFTP if you are able to connect to your server via SSH.

`phpseclib` handles the SFTP connection without the need to install an extension. For an example on how to download a file  with SFTP go [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#get).

Comment: this is not an answer , firstly it is an comment, and second thing op said ,`i do not know how to set the ftp account directory`

Comment: @ArshSingh FTP is not SFTP. The second question is related to a ftp server which you don't have to use if you use SFTP.

Comment: @Fairy Thank you. But my website is in a web hosting that does not allows ssh.

Comment: @f.n174 But your game server allows SSH. You can use PHP to open a SFTP connection to your game server and download the file from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a webserver installed on your vps, you can use an sftp connection with php, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687607/php-download-from-remote-server-via-sftp) to help you implement it.

sFTP being available by default on most linux OSs you shouldn't have much trouble doing this;