# how can I set suspend mode automatically to my site while updating via ftp

Tags: php, apache, ftp

Whenever I want to update my project to web host, I have to set suspend state via control panel or I have to set in code manually as follow.

```
<?
$SUSPEND=true; //setting manually before ftp upload
if($SUSPEND)
  redirect("busy.php");
?>
```

Is there any rapid and efficient way to set to suspend mode during ftp update. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following apache mod rewrite trick that I tested successfully.
 1. rename your **busy.php** to other name (eg. **restricted.php**)
 2. redirect to busy.php if file exists using following code in **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/busy.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ busy.php
```

3. before updating your ftp, change **restricted.php** to **busy.php**
4. after updating complete, rename back busy.php to **restricted.php**.
   If you are updating your project to online server with php ftp client via localhost (without ftp client like filezila), you can even attach **step 3** at the top of ftp process queue and attach **step 4** to end of ftp processes.
   this will set suspend mode automatically.
   I hope this is faster approach than manually setting suspend variable in source code. to prevent unnecessary access to restricted.php in normal condition, you should also restrict to **restricted.php** file in apache rewrite rule.

Comment: thanks!, nice hacking, it works for me. But what is your suggestion about php ftp client. do you mean update project with another ftp client php project. I currently update with ftp client coffee cup, please explain me, Thanks

Comment: you should learn about sftp in php.I think [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php) will be useful.