# I can not connect to my server sftp with ssh2_auth_password in php , but this work if I use FileZilla. This is my code :

Tags: php, sftp

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('sftp://xx.xx.xx.xx', 22) or die ('fail');
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password')) {

  echo "Authentication Successful!\n";

} else {

  die('Authentication Failed...');

}


// my result is: fail ;
```

Comment: Why are you using the `sftp://` prefix?

Comment: my goodness, that's what makes this did not work. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put sftp://. Just the IP should be fine.

Also please format your code correctly for Stack Overflow.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Filezilla, i think has nothing related in functions to php as it is not coded on it.

I would recommend you to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23409857/6487520)

EDIT: [Also check this from the php manual, sftp connections.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

Please let me know if this works for you,

Tom