# How to use SFTP in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

a quick question, currently im using this line to scan file in other site
"$sfs = scandir('ftp://'"
but i was wondering what if the site is using SFTP - SSH, should i still use the command below but instead of ftp i'll use sftp?
"$sfs = scandir('sftp://'""

I will really appreciate your answer. thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SFTP with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php)

Answer (score -1):

SFTP has a COMPLETE guide at This [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php).

You should make a connection first and then you can tansfer files.

(copy the stream variable in example below at your own direction.

create a new file by fopen and then print the $stream in the new file)

example from php.net:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');
?>
```