# Using cURL to connect to SFTP server

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I'm trying to get a .csv file from a SFTP server, and then save it locally. I'm using the following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php

$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$host = 'order.domain.com';
$file = 'filename.csv';

$remote = "sftp://$user:$pass@$host/$file";
$local = getcwd() . '/' . $file;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $remote);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
file_put_contents($local, curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

It seems to be creating the `filename.csv` file in the current working directory, however it is blank.

It appears maybe the curl isn't connecting to the remote server? Maybe the curl isnt set up for SFTP?

Comment: Show us [curl log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3757071/850848).

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php):

> currently supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap protocols

Note that SFTP and FTP are, despite the similar names, *very* different.

If you want SFTP, then you'll need to use a tool designed to work with it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php).

Comment: I've already tried to use the SSH2 extention for PHP but I couldn't get it to work. After hours of trying to get it to work I found out it requires 2 other PHP library's to be installed, and when I looked up those librarys they were just a bunch of files with no directions on how to use them.

The other solution I had looked into already phpsecl which I couldn't get to work either as it requires composer which needs to run my php.ini which it couldnt do because curl is enabled?

Comment: Also from what I read cURL does support SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP). I had found numerous examples here on stack overflow and a few other blogs, but couldn't get them to work personally.