# CURL through PHP with SFTP support

Tags: php, curl, ubuntu-16.04, sftp

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, running PHP7.0 and Magento2. I have installed a Magento Plugin which requires CURL SFTP to send an XML product feed to a remote server.

I noticed that the default CURL installed with Ubuntu does not support SFTP, so I followed instructions to re-compile it on the server, and now has support.

```
~$ curl -V
curl 7.62.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.62.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 libssh2/1.5.0
Release-Date: 2018-10-31
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

However, I did not realize that PHP has its own CURL library, and I don't know how to modify it to provide SFTP support.

I tried issuing "$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl" and it results in:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-curl is already the newest version (7.0.32-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

However, this is not what is reported when I run phpinfo(). It is a different version and also SFTP protocol is not listed.

```
curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.47.0
Age 3
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
```

I'm not sure what next step to take is..

Comment: You can always `exec()` or similar and access the command line tools of the host system - just be extra aware of the potential security issues.  Or there may be a better way to do it - what are you trying to get done?

Comment: I had to do something very similar and the following link worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php

Comment: Thank you for the comments, yes, as a last resort I will look at re-programming the 3rd party plugin but I don't want to do that because then I can never upgrade it or receive support.  In response to what I'm trying to get done, it is to get a google shopping feed setup on Magento2