# "Couldn't connect to ssl" when using ftp_ssl_connect to connect to port 22

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

While trying to connect the server through `ftp_ssl_connect` I'm facing two issues.

```
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server, <port_num>, 20)
$login_result = ftp_login( $conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );
```

1. In this above command while using the `port_num` as 22 it showing the message

   > Couldn't connect to ssl

   But while using 0 as `port_num` its getting connected.
2. There other issue was, while using 0 as `port_num` the `ftp_login` throws the following error

   > Warning: ftp_login(): Command not implemented for that parameter

Note: I have tried to connect the server through FileZilla – it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The `ftp_ssl_connect` connects using FTPS protocol (FTP over TLS/SSL).

The port 22 is used for SFTP protocol (over SSH).

Those are completely different protocols.

See [How to SFTP with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4689540/850848)